# Something is accessing the internet on my computer. How do I know what exactly?

Tags: internet

How can I determine what programs access internet on my PC? I suspected it's `bitcoin-qt`.

But how do I know for sure?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: bitcoin-qt [does not provide a mechanism to limit outgoing bandwidth usage](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=175160.0). Huge outward network traffic by the program is a [very](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=100779.0) [common](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=174354.0) [complaint](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=150498.0), apparently.

Comment: Yea but I turned off bitcoin-qt already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) from SysInternals. To quote from the website:

> TCPView is a Windows program that will show you detailed listings of
>   all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system, including the local and
>   remote addresses and state of TCP connections. On Windows Server 2008,
>   Vista, and XP, TCPView also reports the name of the process that owns
>   the endpoint. TCPView provides a more informative and conveniently
>   presented subset of the Netstat program that ships with Windows. The
>   TCPView download includes Tcpvcon, a command-line version with the
>   same functionality.

Comment: And what if he's running bitcoin on MacOS or Linux?

Comment: apologies for the windows centric answer

Comment: @tink - He would have to find an alternative.  Since the question is already vague RJ did his best to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

A bit heavy artillery but also an option. You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (or just `tcpdump` if in Linux) and see through which port the data is being sent.

**If in Windows**:

```
netstat -aon
```

`-a` - Display all connections

`-o` - Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection

`-n` - Displays addresses and port numbers

Then you can just use the Task Manager processes tab to relate a process ID to an app. (You'll have to add a PID column from View menu).

**If in Linux**:

```
netstat -nap
```

`-a` - Show both listening and non-listening (for TCP this means established connections) sockets

`-n` - Show numerical addresses

`-p` - Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs

Comment: If you take out the -n, it will resolve host names, and not just IP addresses.

Comment: Well, it will just  show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names

Answer (score 1):

You don't mentioned which OS you are using. but I always used **NetBalancer** software in **Windows OS** to know that which **Software** transfer data from Internet.

You can **block download or upload** or change **priority of download or upload**.

You can download it from this link: http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/

Answer (score 0):

Run netstat -an | grep ':80' at the command prompt, which will show processes are using port 80 (HTTP), or netstat -an, and look for processes using port 80, in Windows (since Windows doesn't really have anything like grep.)

Comment: -ab would be a better option since that would give you the process name.

Comment: windows has `find` btw